# JVM: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1

Tags: kotlin, jvm, compiler-construction

This started happening after switching from kotlin 1.8.22 to 1.9.+

I am using the `jvm` plugin, not Android as in other questions

```
plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.20"
```

Errors look like this:

```
Kotlin: Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/tonis/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.20/e58b4816ac517e9cc5df1db051120c63d4cde669/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
```

If I build with `./gradlew`, then build works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: set the compiler version to 1.9.+ in IntelliJ settings

[image]